# Reading XML with Schema XSD

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xsd

I have a problem with the reading an xml, that was created saving the same schema that i used to read.

When I read a DataTable, for example Person, that has one row, the DataTable read the row but show me like all columns where null, when all columns are not null.

The code I use is the following

```
private DataSet LoadShema(string path)
{
    string _archivoXsd = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory +"Scheme.xsd";//HERE IS WHERE THE .XSD FILE IS

    DataSet esquemaXSD = new DataSet();
    string archivoXml = path;
    FileStream FsXSD = new FileStream(_archivoXsd, FileMode.Open);
    FileStream FsXML = new FileStream(archivoXml, FileMode.Open);

    XmlTextReader xtrXSD = new XmlTextReader(FsXSD);
    try
    {
        esquemaXSD.ReadXmlSchema(xtrXSD);
        xtrXSD.Close();
        FsXSD.Close();

        XmlTextReader xtrXML = new XmlTextReader(FsXML);
        esquemaXSD.ReadXml(xtrXML);
        xtrXML.Close();
        FsXML.Close();
    }
    catch
    {
    }
    return esquemaXSD;
}
```

This is how I load the xml in the scheme, then another thing I do is assigning:

```
_dtPerson = new DataTable();
_dtPerson = esquemaXSD.Tables["Person"];
```

and for last, what I do is the following:

```
if (_dtPerson.Rows.Count == 1)
{
    string name = Convert.ToString(_dtPerson.Rows[0]["Name"]); 
}
```

and when i do the last code line, an exception that said "Can not convert DBNull object to other types".

Comment: mind adding your xsd / xml file please

Comment: In the XML File that you are reading is Name element null or even there? Is nillable set to true for the name element?

Comment: 1. Remove that try/catch block - it's preventing you from seeing any exceptions. 2. Your two `FileStream` instances, and your two `XmlReader` instances, need to be in `using` blocks. 3. Don't use `new XmlTextReader()`. That's been deprecated since .NET 2.0. Use `XmlReader.Create` instead.